# JQuery Array Post to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I post with Ajax 3 arrays, each one for every column. I calculate the sum in PHP, then I echo it in every .totalCol child. I want to post only one array called data, that contains the 3 columns, calculate the sum and echo back, and the same with rows.I want to make it dynamic because when I click "+" button of table It will increment rows and columns And I want to calculate it too.

This is How I calculate the columns:

HTML TABLE:

```
<table id="sum_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum1" /></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum2"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum3"/></td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum1"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum2"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum3"/></td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum1"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum2"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum3"/></td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class ="totalCol">
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<button id="tabla">+</button>
<button id="moes">Hide/Show</button>
```

POST OF COLUMNS:

```
$(document).on('change',function(){

       var col1 = [];
       var col2 = [];
       var col3 = [];

       // collect all data from table col1
       $.each($('table td input.sum1'), function(k, v){
           col1.push($(v).val());
       });

       // collect all data from table col2
       $.each($('table td input.sum2'), function(k, v){
           col2.push($(v).val());
       });

       // collect all data from table col3
       $.each($('table td input.sum3'), function(k, v){
           col3.push($(v).val());
       });

       // send data to server
       $.ajax({
           url: 'suma.php',
           type: 'post',
           data: {'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3': col3,},
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data){

               // insert your server-calculated data to dom
               $('.totalCol td:nth-child(1)').text(data.SumCol1);
               $('.totalCol td:nth-child(2)').text(data.SumCol2);
               $('.totalCol td:nth-child(3)').text(data.SumCol3);
           }
       }); 
});
```

PHP CALC:

```
<?php
$SumCol1 = _sumUp($_POST['col1']);
$SumCol2 = _sumUp($_POST['col2']);
$SumCol3 = _sumUp($_POST['col3']);

    echo json_encode(array(
        "SumCol1" => $SumCol1, 
        "SumCol2" => $SumCol2, 
        "SumCol3" => $SumCol3
            ));

function _sumUp($data)
{
    $sum = 0;

    foreach($data as $k => $v)
    {
        $sum += $v;
    }

    return $sum;
}
?>
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: I haven't read it in detail but this looks like it might help... https://www.zulius.com/how-to/send-multidimensional-arrays-php-with-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change',function(){

       var columnValues={}, rowValues={};
       // columnValues will look like this:
       // columnValues={columnNumber:[value, value, value]}
       // rowValues the same:
       // rowValues={rowNumber:[value, value, value]}
       // First, iterate through the rows
       $("#sum_table tr").each(function(rowIndex){
          $("td input", $(this)).each(function(colIndex){
            var value=$(this).val();
            // indexes need +1 to get the row number, because 
            // the indexes are 0-based.
            if (undefined===columnValues[colIndex+1]){
              columnValues[colIndex+1]=[];
            }
            if (undefined===rowValues[rowIndex+1]){
              rowValues[rowIndex+1]=[];
            }
            rowValues[rowIndex+1].push(value);
            columnValues[colIndex+1].push(value);
          });
       });

       // send data to server
       $.ajax({
           url: 'suma.php',
           type: 'post',
           data: {rows:rowValues, columns:columnValues},
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data){
               // insert your server-calculated data to dom
           }
       }); 

});
```

In the PHP you'd access them like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $rowNumber => $values){
    // $values is an array with all the values in the row
}
foreach ($_POST['columns'] as $columnNumber => $values){
    // $values is an array with all the values in the column
}
?>
```

---

About arrays in `$.ajax`:
Objects sent by `$.ajax` becomes arrays in php. No matter the level.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'arraytest.php',
     data: {
         hello: {
             foo: 'bar'
         },
         world: {
             life: 'isgreat'
         }
     }
 });
```

arraytest.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['hello']['foo']; // outputs bar
echo $_POST['world']['life']; // outputs isgreat

?>
```

---

If you want to calculate the columns with jQuery/javascript,

```
$(document).on('change',function(){

       var col1sum = 0;
       var col2sum = 0;
       var col3sum = 0;

       // collect all data from table col1
       $.each($('table td input.sum1'), function(k, v){
           col1sum+=parseInt($(v).val());
       });

       // collect all data from table col2
       $.each($('table td input.sum2'), function(k, v){
           col2sum+=parseInt($(v).val());
       });

       // collect all data from table col3
       $.each($('table td input.sum3'), function(k, v){
           col3sum+=parseInt($(v).val());
       });
});
```

Comment: I should replace  var col1 = [];var col2 = [];var col3 = []; with:
var col1sum = 0;
       var col2sum = 0;
       var col3sum = 0;?

Comment: That was just to point out the distinction. The difference is the `parseInt()` function. It turns the strings in the sum-column values into integers so you can do math-operations on them :)

Comment: "Is possible to send only one array that contains the 3 arrays of each column. Calculate the columns, and another array that contains 3 more arrays of each row and Calculate the Rows?"  Well, As you See in my code I post with Ajax the 3 columns, I calculate the sum in PHP, then I echo it in every .totalCol child. I want to post only one array called data, that contains the 3 columns, calculate the sum and echo back, and the same with rows.I want to make it dynamic because when I click "+" button of table It will increment rows and columns And I want to calculate it too.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation :P

Comment: No prob. But please add the explanation you gave me to the question, so that others can understand it if they run into a similar problem :)

Comment: I dont have to change nothing in the html/Javascript code really? Only in the PHP?

Comment: Everything is changing in the javascript code. So read the first part of the answer again. If you still don't get it, we'll move this into the chat and take it from there :)